# Creating a docker service is not also creating a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am trying to create a docker container in a swarm. I am expecting to see the service when I execute "docker service ls", and to see a container running when I execute "docker ps". I see the service but not the container.

```
[root@docker01-staging dcater]# docker service create --name dbcservice alpine ping 127.0.0.1
lm2b7g3kbnbn11m33y15bplqf
overall progress: 1 out of 1 tasks
1/1: running   [==================================================>]
verify: Service converged


[root@docker01-staging dcater]# docker service ls
ID                  NAME                             MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                                                                       PORTS
maad961bcum4        dbcservice                       replicated          1/1                 alpine:latest

[root@docker01-staging dcater]# docker ps --filter name=dbcservice
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer (roughly). I'm not sure I have the terminology right, but docker01-staging is the management node. I checked docker02-staging, and that's actually where the process is running:

```
[root@docker02-staging dcater]# docker ps --filter name=dbcservice
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
3f30b6fa3d40        alpine:latest       "ping 127.0.0.1"    56 minutes ago      Up 56 minutes                           dbcservice.1.fke9ljd8brpwzhklzqy0agt1r
```

Comment: You can use  `docker service ps dbcservice ` on your management node

Answer (score 0):

[`docker ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) is a docker level command that talks to the docker daemon running on the same node that `docker ps` is run, whereas in the context of Docker Swarm, `docker service` is a swarm level command, querying the swarm state. Thus `docker ps` must always be executed on each node in the swarm to see the running containers.

There is also [`docker node ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/node_ps/) which is a swarm level command that will show the containers running on swarm nodes using the swarm node name. Use [`docker node ls`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/node_ls/) to show the swarm node names.